# Consume multiple JMS messages in a single commit with Spring Integration

Tags: jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

What is the most elegant way to consume multiple JMS messages in a single transaction in Spring Integration without storing the message again in an Aggregator backed by a persistent Message Store?

In an previous project based on IBM Integration Bus this feature (IBM calls it Commit Count) was very helpful to increase message throughput.

Comment: How had you configured the container configuration? Is it possible to share your implementation?  Im also in need of consuming multiple messages from Queue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55107244/hibernate-batch-to-insert-bulk-entities-from-queue-topic

Comment: @AlagammalP sorry, in the end I did not have to implement it; back then I just had to do a feature comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Spring Batch `BatchMessageListenerContainer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/5a803937c71f5bb670d434a004b08830344b779c/spring-batch-infrastructure-tests/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/container/jms/BatchMessageListenerContainer.java).